# Multiple Authentication Mode - Episerver Sites

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication, episerver

We setup multiple Websites based on single Assembley. All sites use Forms authentication mode, set on single Web.config file. Now we need to setup an Intranet site based on the same assembley (as well as same Web.config file) but this time it should authenticate users with Windows authentication mode.

Can anyone be able to give some guidelines about this?
It would be ideal if we can do it with IIS7 module without tweaking the Web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds impossible. You need to put the "Windows Authentication" site in it's own directory. The Web.config (and linked configs) and License.config needs to be unique for that site. But the rest of the application files can be an exact copy of the other dir.